# How to get image id using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, attributes, onload

I have written code like this. `<img id='test_img' src='../../..' />`

I want to get the id of this image on image load like,

```
$(img).load(function() {
// Here I want to get image id i.e. test_img
});
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: this.id inside your load function.

Comment: Give consideration to @Andy E's advice. It doesn't make sense to create a jQuery object and call a method to extract a property value that is available to you via a direct reference to the property name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(img).load(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   //etc
});
```

good luck!!

**edit:**

```
   //suggested by the others (most efficient)
   var id = this.id;

   //or if you want to keep using the object
   var $img = $(this);
   var id = $img.attr("id")
```

Comment: Thanks to all. I think you all are correct. I tried all answers and all worked. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `$(this).attr('id')`, it's taking the long, inefficient route.  Just `this.id` is necessary and it avoids re-wrapping the element with jQuery and the execution of the *attr()* function (which maps to the property anyway!).

```
$(img).load(function() {
   alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
    $('img#test_img').bind('load', function() {
        console.log(this.id);  //console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(img).load(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```